# How do I interact with NSObject from JSON?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm working in Swift and had a question.

I've been able to successfully get data back from APIs as arrays (the JSON returned starts with [] thus is an array) but one particular API i'd like to use returns nested objects (the JSON starts with {}'s instead of []'s so it's not an array structurally. Here is the data. As you can see, the top level is UserRestoreData, and inside it has two 2nd level components: FavoriteMeals, and FavoriteDrinks. They themselves have any number of children representing meals or drinks, and those in turn have any number of ingredients.

```
{"UserRestoreData":[
    {"FavoriteMeals":
      [
       {"FoodID":"1","Title":"Veal Marsala", 
        "Ingredients":{"IngredientID":"1","Name":"Veal"}
       }
      ]
    },
    {"FavoriteDrinks":
      [
       {"DrinkID":"1","Title":"Mint Mojito"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So when I run this code it functions (doesn't crash)

```
 var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "MYURL"))
 let restoreData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSObject
```

And if I were to println restoreData, I get back everything perfectly.
What do I do from here, though? Like how do I actually interact with this NSObject? Is there a way to say "ok now get me the favorite drink child of this object"? I'm having a difficult time finding information online (mostly everything seems to be about NSArray, which I understand and have successfully done).

Is there a way to just deserialize this to an object? Do I cast it somehow? Do I make it into an NSArray and iterate through the response? What do I do with this thing? Sorry if that's a vague question just curious how I could somehow iterate over it or access parts of it.

Thanks so much!

Comment: It is not an `NSObject`, it is an `NSDictionary`, just cast it. Best to spend a little time to read-up on [JSON](http://json.org), also dictionaries.

Comment: thanks and will continue reading (i'm still very new)! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `as NSObject` you can do `as NSDictionary` and then access the content like you would a normal `NSDictionary`